# React-the state is already updated, but when calling setstate again, the value is still the old value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I enter a fromAmount which is larger than the current toAmount, then toAmount value is expected to become fromAmount + $1.

```js
    const initialObj = {
      fromAmount: '',
      toAmount: '',
      comment: ''
    };
    const [itemObj, setItemObj] = useState(initialObj);

    const setItemFieldHandler = (key, value) => {
      console.log("set", key, value);
      console.log("old state: ", itemObj);
      
      const newState = {
        ...itemObj,
        [key]: value
      };
      
      console.log("new state: ", newState);
      
      setItemObj(newState);
    };


    const handleFromAmountInput = useCallback((value) => {
       setItemFieldHandler('fromAmount', value);
      //check if from amount > to amount, 
      // then set toAmount = fromAmount + 1
      if(areBothAmountsValid()) {
         const newToAmount = value + 1;
         handleToAmountInput(newToAmount);
      }
    }, [itemObj]);


    const handleToAmountInput = useCallback((value => {
      setItemFieldHandler('toAmount', value);
    }, [itemObj]);
    }
```

The current from-amount is 1, to-amount is 5. If I change from-amount to 10, the console log is:

```html
set fromAmount 10
old state: 
  {
    fromAmount: 1,
    toAmount: 5,
    comment: ''
  }
new state: 
   {
    fromAmount: 10,
    toAmount: 5,
    comment: ''
  }

set toAmount 11
old state: 
  {
    fromAmount: 1,
    toAmount: 5,
    comment: ''
  }
new state: 
   {
    fromAmount: 1,
    toAmount: 11,
    comment: ''
  }
```

What confuses me is that, fromAmount is already set as 10, why when calling handleToAmountInput(), the fromAmount's value is still 1.

At first, I thought it is because the setState is async, so I used setTimeOut to make handleToAmountInput() running after like 5s to test, but the issue is still the same.

Does anyone know the reason and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `setItemFieldHandler` to your `useCallback` deps, otherwise they'll just hold the old reference. Also, `setState` is an asynchronous operation, if you want access to the previous value when working with it, pass a function to your `setState` call, the function will receive the previous state value.

```js
const setItemFieldHandler = (key, value) => {
  setItemObj((cur) => {
    return {...cur, [key]: value}
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you! It works!